# MenuItemDefinition property "requiredPermissionName" is missing from 5.2.0 release (and pre-release)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

There seems to be a breaking change in the latest release (5.2.0)

To replicate:

1. download the latest stable template for mvc core
2. Update all nuget packages to latest stable

The property `requiredPermissionName` is no longer available

Any steps to overcome would be appreciated...

**Sample Code from Template (.net core MVC)**

```
public class GpNavigationProvider : NavigationProvider
{
    public override void SetNavigation(INavigationProviderContext context)
    {
        context.Manager.MainMenu
            .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.Home,
                    L("HomePage"),
                    url: "",
                    icon: "home",
                    requiresAuthentication: true
                )
            ).AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    PageNames.Tenants,
                    L("Tenants"),
                    url: "Tenants",
                    icon: "business",
                    requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants
                )
```

Compile Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1739
>   The best overload for 'MenuItemDefinition' does not have a parameter named 'requiredPermissionName'
>   ...\5.1.1\aspnet-core\src\Gp.Web.Mvc\Startup\GpNavigationProvider.cs   29  Active

Comment: also tried against pre-release version of template...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change is straightforward:

```cs
// requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants,
permissionDependency: new SimplePermissionDependency(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants),
```

`requiredPermissionName` was deprecated in version 2.2 in July 2017.

It was removed in version 5.2 that was released yesterday, after 3 major versions and more than 2.5 years.

References:

- [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#2289](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2289) (ABP 2.2)
- [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#5191](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/5191) (ABP 5.2)

Comment: The template(s) will be updated: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#5306 (comment 588239620)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5306#issuecomment-588239620)